# RegEx for replacing everthing and new lines in between two words

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am looking for a javascript regex for deleting all lines between two words including the words. I could find something like this

```
Dim input = "one two three four START four five four five six END seven"
Dim output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=START.*)four(?=.*END)", "test")
```

This is for VB and in addition, it does not work for multiple lines and also delete both start and end.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: which laguage is it?

Comment: Tagged JS, but you say *this is for VB*...

Comment: There is a [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method in javascript as well.

Comment: Not that  look behind '?<=' is only supported by chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/GUNYUO/1) can capture your undesired text in between `start` and `end` including new lines:

```
START([\s\S]*)END
```

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph visualizes the expression, and if you want, you can test other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Basic Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet returns runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop for performance. You could simply remove the for and that might be what you may be looking for:

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'anything you wish before START four five four \n \n \n \n five six END anything you wish after';
 const regex = /(.*START)([\s\S]*)(.*END)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1 $3");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### Edit

If you wish to replace one word in a string with new lines, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/PjQFDu/1) might be helpful:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emma it working great. Unfortunately I do not have credit to give the thumbs up

Comment: Emma what happens if I want to change a specific word inside a multi-line text? For example change "football" to " boxing"  in  s="Here is football match. I want to replace football with something else that also consider to change footballA too"

Comment: Emma thanks. I found another issue. Assume that I have a Json that I read it as a string. Assume one of the keys of the Json is dog ( but it could be Dog or dOg). How could I remove that key and value and comma separator of that line with regular expression and javascript?  For example : `{ "someElements":"Could be here","dog":"is an animal", "animals":{"blabla":"blabla"}}` So I want to change it to `{ "someElements":"Could be here","animals":{"blabla":"blabla"}}`  Thanks!

Comment: @codeProtect you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left side of the answer